# Help: LineageOS 20.0 stuck in boot animation

Tags: lineageos

I have **LineageOS** on **Google Pixel 4A**.

Yesterday I restarted it, and it was stuck in the boot animation!

I tried upgrading my LOS 19.1 to *LOS 20.0* using instructions here [https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/sunfish/upgrade](https://https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/sunfish/upgrade) But it looks the problem isn't solved, and the phone is still stuck in boot animation.

Can someone help me please? I'm currently without a phone and I don't want to lose my data..

Comment: I did not want to delete it because someone thankfully commented..

Comment: I am not familiar with LineageOS but to me it looks like flashing stock Pixel image (and losing data) is the only way now. You can subsequently switch to LineageOS //Choice is between having a functional device or losing data

Comment: Thank you, I managed to delete the file, but the phone is still stuck in boot animation! I updated the issue above..

Answer (score 0):

I ended up formatting the phone completely..